# How to show distinct records on the basis of specific columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named PayGrade in which I have few records. I want to show distinct data but on the basis of specific columns

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('PayGrade'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [PayGrade];
END;
GO

CREATE TABLE [PayGrade] (
    [PayGradeID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [ChangeDate] VARCHAR(255),
    [PayGrade] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [Pay] INTEGER NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([PayGradeID])
);
GO

INSERT INTO PayGrade([ChangeDate],[PayGrade],[Pay]) VALUES('2017-07-22 13:38:26','Grade 12','10000');
INSERT INTO PayGrade([ChangeDate],[PayGrade],[Pay]) VALUES('2018-01-31 02:33:02','Grade 12','10000');
INSERT INTO PayGrade([ChangeDate],[PayGrade],[Pay]) VALUES('2018-01-31 18:30:36','Grade 14','15000');
```

With this query I am getting the respective output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ChangeDate, PayGrade, Pay
FROM PayGrade
```

Output:

```
Change Date         PayGrade    Pay
2017-07-22 13:38:26 Grade 12    10000
2018-01-31 02:33:02 Grade 12    10000
2018-01-31 18:30:36 Grade 14    15000
```

Desired Output:

```
Change Date         PayGrade    Pay
2017-07-22 13:38:26 Grade 12    10000
2018-01-31 18:30:36 Grade 14    15000
```

Comment: What's the rational, you only want the oldest records?

Comment: @HoneyBadger You meant to say `rationale`, with a trailing `e`.  I can do grammar and queries.  Yay!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, go you! Thanks for pointing out the typo (shame the edit window is passed now).

Comment: @HoneyBadger becasue that's when pay grade was first assigned the employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Group By` and `Min` function to do this-

```
SELECT MIN(ChangeDate) as ChangeDate, PayGrade, Pay
FROM PayGrade
GROUP BY PayGrade, Pay
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output would seem to imply that you want, for a group of a given pay grade and pay, the first/oldest record.  If so, then we can use row number as follows:

```
SELECT
    [Change Date],
    PayGrade,
    Pay
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PayGrade, Pay ORDER BY [Change Date]) rn
    FROM PayGrade
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```